# php script returning error 'Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' whereas the sql command works fine

Tags: php, sql

The following query runs fine in phpmyadmin and rows get inserted but in php script its causing problems . Please suggest solution

```
INSERT INTO NamazTiming 
(`FajarAzan`,`FajarZamat`,`ZoharAzan`,`ZoharJamat`,`AsarAzan`,`AsarJamat`,`Maghrib`,`IshaAzan`,`IshaJamat`,`JumaAzan`,`JumaJamat`,`Taraweeh`,`FromDate`,`ToDate`,`MasjidID_FK`)
VALUES
('04:25:07',
'04:25:07',
'5:48:07',
'04:25:07',
'12:29:07',
'04:25:07',
'15:49:07',
'04:25:07',
'19:08:07',
'04:25:07',
'20:31:07',
'04:25:07',
'2014-06-11',
'2014-06-20',
'39')
```

Error given by script

```
'Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The following is in my php script

```
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO NamazTiming 
(`FajarAzan`,`FajarZamat`,`ZoharAzan`,`ZoharJamat`,`AsarAzan`,`AsarJamat`,`Maghrib`,`IshaAzan`,`IshaJamat`,`JumaAzan`,`JumaJamat`,`Taraweeh`,`FromDate`,`ToDate`,`MasjidID_FK`)
VALUES
('$FajarAzan',
'$FajarJamat',
'$ZoharAzan',
'$ZoharJamat',
'$AsarAzan',
'$AsarJamat',
'$Maghrib',
'$IshaAzan',
'$IshaJamat',
'$JumaAzan',
'$JumaJamat',
'$Taraweeh',
'$FromDate',
'$ToDate',
'$MasjidID')") or die(mysql_error());
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please run this and copy or screenshot the output.
SHOW KEYS FROM NamazTiming WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'

Comment: please check main post ! Added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the primary key does have the auto increment value, it looks like you may have restored data or the auto increment value has been reset.

This query should resolve this:

```
SELECT max(NamazTimingID_PK)+1 FROM NamazTiming LIMIT 1;
ALTER TABLE NamazTiming AUTO_INCREMENT = <result>;
```

Replace  with the returned value from the select statement.

Comment: please formulate an exact query to run your query does not run #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( SELECT max(NamazTimingID_PK)+1 FROM NamazTiming LIMIT 1 )' at line 1